# Remove click-option from iframe

Tags: iframe, instagram

I would be really, really happy if someone could help me with removing the click (link) option from this iframe. I just want the image to be not clickable.

```
<iframe src="http://snapwidget.com/in/?u=bW9sbGVrcnVrbWFrZXJpfGlufDI1MHwxfDF8fG5vfDB8bm9uZXxvblN0YXJ0fG5vfG5v&ve=120215" title="Instagram Widget" class="snapwidget-widget" allowTransparency="true" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" style="border:none; overflow:hidden; width:200px; height:200px"></iframe>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can put a transparent div in front of the iframe.

```css
.iframeContainer{
position:relative;
border:1px solid;
width:200px;
height:200px;
}

.iframeBlocker{
position:absolute;
width:100%;
height:100%;
background:#000;
opacity:0.5;
}
```

```html
    <div class="iframeContainer">
     <div class="iframeBlocker"></div>
     <iframe src="http://snapwidget.com/in/?u=bW9sbGVrcnVrbWFrZXJpfGlufDI1MHwxfDF8fG5vfDB8bm9uZXxvblN0YXJ0fG5vfG5v&ve=120215" title="Instagram Widget" class="snapwidget-widget" allowTransparency="true" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" style="border:none; overflow:hidden; width:200px; height:200px"></iframe>
    </div>
```